# NSMutableArray leaks warning addressed by the Instrument

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, instruments, memory-leaks

I am using Instrument leaks tools to check leaks in the code.

```
//MyClass.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *marrProperty;

//MyClass.m
NSSortDescriptor *createdTime = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdTime" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];             
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.anManagedObj.aRelationships sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:createdTime]];
[createdTime release];
NSMutableArray *marr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedArray];
self.marrProperty = marr;
[marr release];
```

After checking with the leaks tool in Instrument, I was told the leaks happened in the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *marr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedArray];
self.marrProperty = marr;
```

I don't know why, because I just alloc and release well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instruments is showing you were the leaked object was allocated, not where it was leaked.

You need to find the extra `retain`.   You can use Instruments to do that;  the Allocations instrument can be configured to track retain/release events.

[This will likely be helpful](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

Comment: Well, i do not know why there is no NSMutableArray in all Heapshots.

Comment: Likely because you are only leaking one.  So, click through that one and check the retain/release history to see where the extra retain is coming from.

Comment: The tracking shows: (Event Type, RefCt), (Malloc, 1), (Retain, 2), (release 1)

Comment: Right.  So you are missing a retain (if you were expecting the objects to go away).

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented a custom setter for marrProperty? This could be a source of memory issues.

Additionally, you might prefer to use `[[sortedArray mutableCopy] autorelease]`, instead of `initWithArray:` followed by a `release`. Simply for code clarity.

If you're not using ARC, make sure that you release marrProperty in -dealloc for that class.

Comment: just @systhesize marrProperty

Comment: The issue does not appear to be in this code. Are you releasing marrProperty in the dealloc method for that class? Retain properties must be released in dealloc.

Comment: Im using ARC, so no need to do dealloc

Comment: If there's no need to dealloc, there's no point in you using release (in fact, it should be an error) - If you're not getting an error from calling release, ARC is not on.

Comment: the property will be autoreleased, i just release an ivar. there is no error.